# iOS push notifications internacionalization: payload's "loc-key" and "loc-args"

Tags: ios, internationalization, apple-push-notifications, nslocalizedstring, payload

I don't find this in the Apple's related documentation: is it mandatory to include the field "loc-args", even if you don't need any argument and it is empty, when providing the field "loc-key"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **loc-key**
>
> A key to an alert-message string in a Localizable.strings file for the current localization (which is set by the user’s language preference). The key string **can be formatted with %@ and %n$@ specifiers to take the variables specified in loc-args**.

([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21))

To me, `can be formatted` means `loc-args` is optional. It would be, of course, very easy to test it yourself and verify.

Answer (score 1):

If your loc-key doesn't contain any args, then you can completely omit the loc-args field.  You can also include it and pass null. Do not pass the empty string.

If you do pass parameters, make sure to include brackets [] around the values, even for one value.